# Как сменить версию PHP в определённой папке сайта имя доступ к php.ini?

Tags: php, apache

Написан сайт на Wordpress с кастомным модулем, который работает с PHP 7.2+
Есть ещё 2 модуля, которые нужно сохранить, как выяснилось, они работают с PHP 5.6 до 7.1 включительно.

Допустим есть:
public_html
— assets
— module_one
— module_two
— index.php

Версия PHP по-умолчанию стоит 7.4, как сделать, чтобы для /public_html/module_one была версия PHP 7.1, при этом остальной сайт работал с 7.4? У хостинга есть режим PHP CGI, в котором мне открывается доступ к файлу php.ini.

(Костыль временный, не кидайтесь тапками)

Comment: Не проще ли подфиксить эти модули для нужной версии?

Comment: можно использовать докер контейнеры https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress и сделать связку между двумя контейнерами - в одном php 7.1 в другом php 8.0 Тот что с php 7.1 работает как api

Comment: @Dmitry фиксы в процессе, но сайт уже улетел в продакшн, поэтому нужно костыльное решение)

Comment: @Mcile хорошее решение, но сайт лежит на шаред хостинге, технически невозможно это сделать(

Comment: Можно еще старые плагины все вырезать, а вместо них сделать обращение по api на свой сервер или арендуемый со всеми пирогами или переехать на выделенный сервер или арендовать на этой же машине еще хостинг с другой версией php и наладить общение между машинами